# variable is not defined, but it is defined as global variable, python

Tags: python, global-variables

I keep getting the error `name 'copyDir is not defined` but it is defined as a global variable in my code. What is wrong? I reviewed some of the other posts here similar to this but still can't understand the problem. Here's the beginning part of my code:

```
import arcpy, os, shutil, re
mapIndex = r'C:\Temp\temp.gdb\MapSets_All'
copydDir = r'D:\MapSheetImages\All_Images'

fields = ['FileSpecDir','is_name']

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(mapIndex,fields):
    arcpy.env.workspace = row[0]
    rstrList = arcpy.ListRasters()

    for dir, folders, files in os.walk(row[0]):
        try:
            if 'CCS27z2e' in folders:
                for r in rstrList:
                    if row[1] in r:
                        rOrigPath = os.path.join(row[0],r)
                        rNewPath = os.path.join(copyDir,r)
                        if not os.path.isfile(rNewPath):
                            arcpy.AddMessage('now copying '+r)
                            shutil.copyfile(rOrigPath,rNewPath)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            arcpy.AddMessage(e)
```

Comment: Your variable is `copydDir`, not `copyDir`. A typo - `copyDir` is not defined.

Comment: the code is very long with the except statement at the end so i didn't post it all, i'll add that part it

Comment: @AndrewDunai oh wow I could not see that thanks!!

Comment: @AndrewDunai It would be apt if you post it as an answer, instead of others

Comment: @BhargavRao Lawrence already did it, so let it be him :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
copydDir = r'D:\MapSheetImages\All_Images'
```

should be:

```
copyDir = r'D:\MapSheetImages\All_Images'
```